# Qt Complex layout for a note-taking app

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have a qt app that uses a very bad technique for resizing. The current approach is to put all the main elements inside a form, and when resizing is happening, change the size and place of the objects through custom code.
It's an ugly, hard to maintain, and not good for future features approach.

What should be done is to use the tools qt have for handling layouts.
I've tried and failed. I would like your help with it.
e
You can take a look at the app here:
https://github.com/nuttyartist/notes

The source is there.
Also, here is a screenshot from the qtcreator form:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMP86.png

I'm okay with creating the layout through code.

Comment: Take a peek at http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by ddriver, you should absolutely work with layouts. They will work fine (in most cases) if you resize your window and it is also possible to cascade widgets with different layouts.

It might be a bit counterintuitive to work with layouts at the very beginning and you have to rethink how to place your widgets, but it is without doubt very rewarding.

Comment: I know about layouts, but I am struggling to implement them in a way that my app will work like it's working now.
Here is what I got:
http://i.imgur.com/6pAFTB0.png
But there are few problems:
1. I want widgets to be at a fixed size I decide. Fixed policy isn't doing it.
2. The space between widgets, between widget and the main window and between layouts to the line should not be there.
3. The closse-minimze-maximize buttons not sit in the way they should. they shouldn't be on the same 'y' axis as the plus and trash buttons, but above them.

Comment: Try a different nesting of the layouts, something like this for example http://i.stack.imgur.com/xRjA7.png

Comment: 1. Why would you need fixed size? This is rarely a good policy. If you really need it, you have to set min size and max size at the same time because fixedSize does not work for reasons undisclosed to me.
2. try setBorderSpacing and setContentsMargins; in the QtDesigner you can set spacing and the margins  for all of the edges individually.
3. For this, you should play around with layoutStretch... the layoutStretch sum of both the left and right layout should be equal and the first number is probably the height ratio of the first widget. If this number is equal as well, they should be aligned

Comment: Alrighty! I think I'm on my way to solving that. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Good to hear :) If you find it applicable, you might also upvote some comments/the answer or mark it as solution, so that others know what to read/what not to write

Comment: The two last comments before my last comment are the answer, but I can't find how to select them as an answer.

Comment: You can merely mark answers as answer, while there is only my one. Comments can only be upvoted